# Recommended way to rotate the tux web server log file

Tags: web-server, log-files

I am considering Tux as the web server for a new CPAN mirror I'm building.  I've got it running and it's very fast but there is one big catch: how am I supposed to rotate the log file?

The log file is configurable, and I am using the default value of /var/log/tux.

One option would be copy-and-truncate; e.g.:

```
cp /var/log/tux /var/log/tux.1
cat /dev/null > /var/log/tux
```

The logrotate application can do that for me but since the log file is binary I am concerned that this might lead to corruption at some point.

If it only corrupts one entry I can live with it - my fear is that the whole log file could be lost.

Anyone with experience care to make a suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this, which I wrote to roll my nginx logs. I looked for some details on the `tux` userspace process but couldn't find any way to get it to reopen it's logs, so you may have to resort to stopping and starting the process.

```
#!/bin/bash

YEAR=`date "+%Y"`
MONTH=`date "+%m"`
DAY=`date "+%d"`

HOSTNAME=`hostname -s`

LOG_FILES="access.log error.log images.log redirect.log ssl.log click.log uploads.log urchin.log user_sites.log"

DATE=$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY

LOG_ROOT=/var/log/
NGINX_LOG_ROOT=$NGINX_LOG_ROOT/nginx

# make path

mkdir -p $NGINX_LOG_ROOT/$DATE

# touch and symlink in new log files

for FILE in $LOG_FILES; do
    LOG_FILE=$NGINX_LOG_ROOT/$DATE/$HOSTNAME.$FILE
    touch $LOG_FILE
    ln -fs $LOG_FILE $NGINX_LOG_ROOT/$FILE
done

# tell nginx to re-open its log files

kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
```

Comment: I don't need the date archiving stuff but it does seem to me that the way to go is to rotate and restart Tux.

Another way would be to change the log name via /prox/sys/net/tux/ but I haven't tested to check if it will start writing to the newly changed log path without a restart.

Answer (score 0):

Before I suggest something ["TUX has never been an integrated part of the official Linux kernel"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUX_web_server). Are you sure you want to maintain kernel patches on your own?

Personally I'd try to create a pipe which tux writes to and then use [rotatelogs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/rotatelogs.html) (from apache) to handle that stuff. Maybe even logger so that it uses syslog directly.

rotatelogs can handle time or size based rotations for you, if you don't send the logs to a central logging server I'd use that, if you do send to a central logging server I'd send it to syslog, just let syslog create another socket which tux will write to (preferrably /var/log/tux), and syslog *should* handle the rest for you...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention we're running Red Hat Enterprise Linux.  RH provides the Tux kernel module and user-land stuff so maintaining it is as simple as "yum install tux" and "yum update".

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit curious here: What do you expect of incoming requests per second since you need a HTTP engine running inside your kernel? Isnt tinyhttpd fast enough?

Comment: It may be - I'm not sure RH provides an RPM package for it though.

Comment: RH does not provide packages for tinyhttpd.  To answer your question, I'm not expecting a huge demand on the server but I would like to keep the memory and CPU footprint low.

Comment: Well, tiny httpd is extremely cheap on resources. Perhaps you should give it a try? I would try anything but running something inside the kernel. Here are the instructions posted on the tiny httpd website:

On Red Hat Linux systems you can use RPM to install thttpd, like so:

    cd /usr/src/redhat/SOURCES
    wget http://www.acme.com/software/thttpd/thttpd-2.25b.tar.gz
    rpm -ta thttpd-2.25b.tar.gz
    rpm -i /usr/src/redhat/RPMS/i386/thttpd-2.25b-1.i386.rpm

Comment: Ok, that looks awful. http://acme.com/software/thttpd/ - scroll a bit down.